# Можно ли сделать так, что-бы бот узнавал id группы в телеграмм?

Tags: telegram, telebot, python-3.8

Как узнать id группы в телеграмм? То есть, что бы мой бот сам узнавал id группы без сторонних ботов. Возможно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держи

```
id = message.chat.id
print(id)
```

Comment: Спасибо, не думал , что все так просто